# BigQuery: JOIN on single matching row

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, scripting

I have two tables, one containing orders with a nested line_items structure and another with a pricing history for each product sku code.

### Orders Table

| order_id | order_date | item_sku | item_quantity | item_subtotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-23-07 | SKU1 | 7 | 12.34 |
|  |  | SKU2 | 1 | 9.99 |
| 2 | 2022-12-07 | SKU1 | 1 | 1.12 |
|  |  | SKU3 | 5 | 32.54 |

### Price History Table

| item_sku | effective_date | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SKU1 | 2022-20-07 | 0.78 |
| SKU2 | 2022-02-03 | 4.50 |
| SKU1 | 2022-02-03 | 0.56 |
| SKU3 | 2022-02-03 | 4.32 |

### Desired Output

| order_id | order_date | item_sku | item_quantity | item_subtotal | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-23-07 | SKU1 | 7 | 12.34 | 0.78 |
|  |  | SKU2 | 1 | 9.99 | 4.50 |
| 2 | 2022-12-07 | SKU1 | 1 | 1.12 | 0.56 |
|  |  | SKU3 | 5 | 32.54 | 4.32 |

I'm trying to get the product cost by finding the cost at the time of the order being placed.

```
SELECT order_id, order_date,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT
    item_sku,
    item_quantity,
    item_subtotal,
    cost.product_cost
    FROM UNNEST(line_items) as items
    JOIN `price_history_table` as cost
    ON items.item_sku = cost.sku AND effective_date < order_date 
  ) AS line_items,
  FROM
  `order_data_table`
```

The above query works but creates a separate line_item array row for each record in the price history table.

How can I match on just the most recent price for that sku. I want to add something like this

`ORDER BY effective_date DESC LIMIT 1`

But can't work out how to add it.

Comment: Yes, I know I've put the dates in a nonsense format. This is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I match on just the most recent price for that sku

You need to add below line into subquery and move join out of select to address correlated subquery issue

```
QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item_sku ORDER BY effective_date DESC)
```

so, the final query will look like below

```
SELECT order_id, order_date,
  ARRAY_AGG(line_item) AS line_items
FROM (
  SELECT order_id, order_date,
      STRUCT(item_sku,
      item_quantity,
      item_subtotal,
      cost.product_cost) AS line_item
  FROM `order_data_table`, UNNEST(line_items) AS items
  JOIN `price_history_table` AS cost
  ON items.item_sku = cost.sku AND effective_date < order_date 
  QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id, order_date, item_sku ORDER BY effective_date DESC)
)
GROUP BY order_id, order_date
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but it's still not working for me. I get the error "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN."

Comment: i will double check and get back here ...

Comment: see update. tested now :o) so should work! please try and let me know

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. My actual query is bit more complex than what I've shared but I've managed to integrate your suggested change with that and it's working brilliantly. A lot to unpack with what's going on there but thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, this still isn't correct. It's only returning about 10% of the rows it should. Roughly 350 rows whereas it should be around 3.7K. Looks like it's something to do with the partition, as if I remove that line, the number of rows is correct (but there is a line_item sub row for each row for a sku in the price history table).

Comment: if you still do not have expected result in your real use case - you might missed something important in your question. consider revisit it and post new one! this said - I think, the current question as it is asked and spec'd is fully answered!

Comment: I have the same issue in the simplified example given in my original question I'm afraid. Just working with this example, I'm trying to understand what's going on in your solution with the array aggregation and the window function. Something between the two is doing something funny.

What's also interesting is that not only do I get a subset of the expected results each time I run the query, I get a different subset of results.

Comment: as you can see I have screenshot of output in my answer  - and it looks quite correct to me based on presented input data in your question. the only reason I can think of why you are not getting same is maybe because as you stated in your comment `Yes, I know I've put the dates in a nonsense format.`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you giving your time to answer me.

I have simplified my example further by taking the date (and effective_date) out of the equation altogether. It still has the same issue but with some interesting observations. It looks like it is only returning records with unique sku codes, hence the subset of data. I'm guessing that this is due to the partition on item_sku. Curious as to why you're not having the same issue in your example.

Comment: Ignore me, I've just gone back to basics and copied your solution. I was missing the date field from the partition. Apologies for wasting your time further!