# Issues connecting Google Data Studio to BigQuery with window function

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a complex BigQuery view that pulls data from various connected Google Sheets along with calculated data from within BigQuery. I'm trying to create a dashboard on top of the view in Data Studio.

I'm having an issue getting my data to show in Data Studio and have isolated it to a particular part of the underlying view in BigQuery.

I had an earlier problem that was answered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73504683/bigquery-join-on-single-matching-row/73519994).

I am running effectively the query from that post, saved as a view and then connected to Data Studio.

```sql
SELECT order_id, order_date,
  ARRAY_AGG(line_item) AS line_items
FROM (
  SELECT order_id, order_date,
      STRUCT(item_sku,
      item_quantity,
      item_subtotal,
      cost.product_cost) AS line_item
  FROM `order_data_table`, UNNEST(line_items) AS items
  JOIN `price_history_table` AS cost
  ON items.item_sku = cost.sku AND effective_date < order_date 
  QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id, order_date, item_sku ORDER BY effective_date DESC)
)
GROUP BY order_id, order_date
```

This query uses a window function and it is this that is causing my issue. Whenever I try to connect to the data I get this.

[image: Data Set Configuration Error]

With the details being

> Data Studio cannot connect to your data set.
>
> Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set

Removing the below line from the query solves the issue but then I don't have the desired data.

```sql
QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id, order_date, item_sku ORDER BY effective_date DESC)
```

Is there a reason why this breaks Data Studio? Can I avoid it? Can I solve the original issue in a different way that doesn't use a window function?

### UPDATE

Looks like there is an [issue in Data Studio where it does not support the QUALIFY function.](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/172699750/bigquery-qualify-function-is-not-supported-by-data-studio?hl=en)

Any suggestions on how I can re-write this query without using QUALIFY?

Comment: If you run the query directly on BigQuery does it works? Have you checked the query history in BigQuery for any errors?

Comment: Yep, all works fine within BigQuery. There are no errors logged when connecting from Data Studio either.

Answer (score 3):

As described in [the issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/250581514?pli=1), the workaround is to **always include the WHERE clause**. Without it, Data Studio gets confused and fails.

I had the same problem and adding `WHERE TRUE` to my queries fixed it without needing any other rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by removing the QUALIFY function and re-writing my query as this

```sql
SELECT order_id, order_date,
  ARRAY_AGG(line_item) AS line_items
FROM (
  SELECT order_id, order_date,
      STRUCT(item_sku,
      item_quantity,
      item_subtotal,
      cost.product_cost,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id, order_date, item_sku ORDER BY effective_date DESC) AS row_num) AS line_item
  FROM `order_data_table`, UNNEST(line_items) AS items
  JOIN `price_history_table` AS cost
  ON items.item_sku = cost.sku AND effective_date < order_date 
)
WHERE line_item.row_num = 1
GROUP BY order_id, order_date
```